# Select by xpath knowing only ending of element's attribute

Tags: python, xml, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

Having such xml file. How can I select only that tag, which `href` attribute ends with `parent`, like third element below.

Determine it by position like
 `elem = tree.findall('{*}CustomProperty')[2]` 
does not fit because some documents might have only one `parent` href, others 5-10 and third might not have such hrefs at all.

I tend to use xpath but can not figure out how can I tell xpath to search for end of attribute match.

Also xpath is not must, I will be glad to use any way that fits to my purpose

**So how can I get `CustomProperty` element which has a `href` attribute that ends with word `parent` ?**

```
 <CustomProperty href="urn:1653267:643562dafewq:cs:46wey5ge:234566">urn:1653267:643562dafewq:cs:46wey5ge:234566:ss</CustomProperty>
 <CustomProperty href="urn:1653267:643562dafewq:cs:46wey5ge:234566">urn:1653267:643562dafewq:cs:46wey5ge:234566:ss</CustomProperty>
 <CustomProperty href="urn:1653267:643562dafewq:cs:46wey5ge:234566:parent">urn:1653267:643562dafewq:cs:46wey5ge:234566:ss</CustomProperty>
```

Thank you in advance for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the contains selector to find the element with an attribute href which contains the word parent

```
//*[contains(@href, 'parent')]
```

or if you are sure about the position of text "parent" you can use the ends-with

```
//*[ends-with(@href, 'parent')]
```

Comment: `ends-with` requires support of xpath 2.0

Comment: @collapsar, how can I determine whether xpath 2.0 is supported? I'm using latest lxml library

Comment: @micgeronimo use a location path that requires xpath 2.0 (eg. The `ends-with` Function in a node test) - your processor should throw an error about 'unsupported feature' or 'syntax error'. Beware that xpath 2 is quite extensive so the processor you are using might not fully support it. Which means consult the docs, if possible ;-)

Comment: @micgeronimo lxml supports XPath 1.0, XSLT 1.0 and its extension, EXSLT - because internally, it makes use of libxslt and libxml2. So, no, XPath 2.0 is not supported.

Answer (score 4):

Does

```
//CustomProperty[contains(@href, 'parent') and substring-after(@href, 'parent') = '']
```

cater to your requirements? One issue with the suggestion is that it fails for href attributes where `parent` occurs more than once.

If your xpath processor supports xpath 2.0, use aberna's suggestion.

Remember to replace the '//' axis by specific paths whereever possible for performance reasons.